# Reference for the dialogue between heraclius and abu sufyan

Tags: hadith, source-identification

There was a dialogue between heraclius and abu sufyan. Then abu sufyan didn't embraced islam yet.

You can find the dialogue [here](https://www.the-faith.com/prophet-muhammad/prophet-legacy/a-dialogue-between-abu-sufyan-and-heraclius/)

But the problem is I can't find any reference for this. Like which hadith recorded this. If you anyone can give a reference for this dialogue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been recorded by Bukhari near the very beginning of his Sahih, in كتاب بدء الوحى, see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/7). And by Muslim in كتاب الجهاد والسير under the title باب كتاب النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم إلى هرقل , see [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/89).

Comment: jazakallah khair for this brother